# Getting error while compiling a code in c++. Numbers like 96 in codeblocks and 128 in devc++ gets printed in output

Tags: c++

i am very new to c++, and i was making a program on converting number to words. but when i run my program some numbers like 96 in codeblocks, 128 in devc++ is getting printed along with the output. also in cout section, i wrote " the number in words before the next words, but it is getting printed after it. The screenshots are 
**Screenshot 1**

[image]

**screenshot 2**

[image]
My code is ( i know its lengthy but i tried to use what i have studied till now)

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <math.h>

    using namespace std;

    bool unit(int unit);
    bool twodigitupto19 (int twodigit, int unitdigit);
    bool unit0 (int spcltens);

    int main ()

    {
        cout << "Welcome frnds, My new program Helps to translate numbers to their english equivalent." << endl;
        cout << "U have to enter the numbers in this format - 000x. \nCurrently only numbers upto 1000 are supported. and after each digit press enter.. plz \n";
        int T, h, t, o;
        cin >> T;
    cin >> h;
    cin >> t;
    cin >> o;
    cout << "U entered\t" << T << h << t << o<< endl;

    if (T==0 && h==0)
    {
        if (t==0 && o!=0)
            {
                cout << unit (o) << " ";
            }
        else if (t==1 && o!=0)
            {
                cout << twodigitupto19 (t, o) << " ";
            }
        else if (t!=0 && o ==0)
        {
                cout << unit0 (t) << " ";
        }
        else if (t!=0 && t!=1 && o!=0)
        {
                cout <<"The number in words is" << unit (o) << unit0 (t) << "\n ";
        }
    }

}

    bool unit(int unit)
    {
        if (unit == 1)
            cout << "one";
        else if (unit == 2)
            cout << "two";
        else if (unit == 3)
            cout << "three";
        else if (unit == 4)
            cout << "four";
        else if (unit == 5)
            cout << "five";
        else if (unit == 6)
            cout << "six";
        else if (unit == 7)
            cout << "seven";
        else if (unit == 8)
            cout << "eight";
        else if (unit == 9)
            cout << "nine";
        //else if (unit == 0)
          //  cout << "zero";
        //else
            //cout << "not a unit digit number." << endl;
    }

    bool twodigitupto19 (int twodigit, int unitdigit)
    {
         if (twodigit == 1 && unitdigit==1)
            cout << "eleven";
        else if (twodigit == 1 && unitdigit==2)
            cout << "twelve";
        else if (twodigit == 1 && unitdigit==3)
            cout << "thirteen";
        else if (twodigit == 1 && unitdigit==4)
            cout << "fourteen";
        else if (twodigit == 1 && unitdigit==5)
            cout << "fifteen";
        else if (twodigit == 1 && unitdigit==6)
            cout << "sixteen";
        else if (twodigit == 1 && unitdigit==7)
            cout << "seventeen";
        else if (twodigit == 1 && unitdigit==8)
            cout << "eighteen";
        else if (twodigit == 1 && unitdigit==9)
            cout << "nineteen";
    }

    bool unit0 (int spcltens)
    {
        if (spcltens==1)
            cout << "ten";
        else if (spcltens==2)
            cout << "twen" << "ty";
        else if (spcltens==3)
            cout << "thir"<< "ty";
        else if (spcltens==4)
            cout << "four" << "ty";
        else if (spcltens==5)
            cout << "fif" << "ty";
        else if (spcltens==6)
            cout << "six"<< "ty";
        else if (spcltens==7)
            cout << "seven" << "ty";
        else if (spcltens==8)
            cout << "eigh" << "ty";
        else if (spcltens==9)
            cout << "nine" << "ty";
    }
```

Comment: No screenshots, no tag spamming please! Provide a [MCVE] please.#

Comment: Yes I did :) It's ok, it's better to post the raw output though :)

Answer (score 1):

`cout << unit (o) << " ";`

Look! You are output the return value of `unit`.

But what does it return, let's see :)

```
bool unit(int unit);
```

So it's a `bool`, either `true` or `false` (those will get outputted as `1` and `0`)

When does the function return?

```
bool unit(int unit)
{
    if (unit == 1)
        cout << "one";
    else if (unit == 2)
        cout << "two";
    else if (unit == 3)
        cout << "three";
    else if (unit == 4)
        cout << "four";
    else if (unit == 5)
        cout << "five";
    else if (unit == 6)
        cout << "six";
    else if (unit == 7)
        cout << "seven";
    else if (unit == 8)
        cout << "eight";
    else if (unit == 9)
        cout << "nine";
    //else if (unit == 0)
      //  cout << "zero";
    //else
        //cout << "not a unit digit number." << endl;
}
```

What, it doesn't even return... So, the return value will be garbage (your compiler should warn you about this though (mine does)).

Those random numbers you see are those garbage values that `unit` returns. The logic is weird because `unit` outputs the numbers already, so you don't even need to return anything from `unit`, less print it.

Just call `unit` (this goes the same for the other 2 functions):

```
if (t == 0 && o != 0)
    unit(o);
```

Comment: To be pedantic, it's "the other ***3*** functions". `int(main)` doesn't return anything either.

Comment: By the way, g++ without `-Wall` doesn't give any warnings on the program.

Comment: @MrLister `int main` doesn't need to return anything. That's weird, I would have thought that g++ warns about this, VS does

Comment: @Rakete1111 [basic.start.main]/5: "If control reaches the end
of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing `return 0;`"

Comment: @kfsone yeah, I know :) That's what I said ;)

Comment: Thnx for the help friends..Rakete1111 it worked. But which compiler do u use..as i use codeblocks and it did not show me that error

Comment: @Aman it's Visual Studio 2015, but GCC/g++ also report it. I think codeblocks uses GCC, try enabling higher warning level